# How to check if time intervals are overlapping in Laravel 4.2/php?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

So i have in a table tm_timekeep(id(pk), start(varchar), end(varchar)) [and a model for it] in a database with some time intervals in HH:MM format. For example:

```
id|start|end  |
---------------
0 |10:00|10:30| 
1 |11:23|11:55|
2 |13:15|15:39|
```

i would like to insert new rows and modify the existent ones if there are no overlappings between intervals.
if i would like to add as interval 11:57-12:40 would be ok, but 09:00-10:20 wouldn't because of 10:00-10:30, same for updateing a row. And if i would like to update a row, I need a function to check the condition before modifying the row. How should i do this?
My current code snippet:

```
public function checkInterval($start, $end){
 $counter = 0;
$timekeepArray = Timekeep::all();
$start = date('H:i',Input::get('start'));
$end = date('H:i',Input::get('end'));
foreach($timekeepArray as $timekeep) 
{
 if($start <= $timekeep->end && $end>=$timekeep->start){
  counter++; //in range
 }
  return counter;
  }
 }
```

After this i check the value of counter, but my problem is, that i always get 0 even if there are overlappings from input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite trivial - convert your time intervals to minutes, eg. 10:00 becomes 10 * 60 + 0 = 600 minutes, ends at 630 correspondingly.

Then, when you are trying to insert or update, and I would suggest you do it in Timekeep model, bound to 'saving' model event (see [Model Events](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#model-events)), you check whether:

1) Pick the last end time in minutes that is less than your new start time (that's a trivial SQL query)
2) See if there is any existing time in between that end time and your new end time - if there is, we have overlapping. Throw an exception, cancel model saving

There are several ways you could convert strings to minutes - you could store integers in MySQL (eg. 600) and then convert them to human readable hours either by defining getAttribute() or making your own methods. Or you could keep storing data as VARCHARs and do simple string manipulations (remove ':', multiply first part by 60) either in SQL or in PHP